# Textmate: Remove a list of email addresses from a larger list

Tags: regex, list, email, grep, textmate

This feels like something that ought to be very simple, but i've been unable to find any way to accomplish it.

i have a list of over 10,000 email addresses in a text file. i have another, shorter list of 100+ addresses i need to remove from the original list. The problem is, there is an unknown number of addresses between each one to be removed.

i want to know: **Is there a way to remove this list of addresses from the main list without doing a find/replace for each of the 100+ addresses individually?**

Comment: To be clear, You want to remove the 100 records from the 1000 records and finally you should get 900 records ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use grep:

```
grep -Fxvf smallfile mainfile
```

it will print lines that, there are only in mainfile and not in smallfile.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use either

1. Python(or any language)
2. Excel

Python: 
  make the larger file A into list_A, smaller file B into list_B
and then just for loop through list_A: if element of list_A exists in list_B, kick it out.

Excel:
  Paste file A to column A, file B to column B. And then column C, using formula "countif" to show if any element of A exists in column B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google sheets to identify the unique values in two different list using few simple steps. Please find the below Demo.

**Step 1:** Create a google sheet and paste the Inputs as below.

[image: Sample Input data]

**Step 2:** Use the add-on's menu choose the choose the remove duplicates add on(if you don't have it by default, you can choose Get Add on's.. and include it to your menu)

[image: choose Add on's]

Step 3: Select the input and output column Ranges.
**First List:**
[image: Input Range 1]

**Second List:**
[image: Input range 2]

**Step 4:** Choose the data type as unique value.
[image: Unique value choice]

**Step 5:** Choose filter options to add or ignore case sensitivity.
[image: filter options]

**Step 6:** Choose the output options(I have included the third column for demo).
[image: Output location]

**Step 7:** The unique values will be filtered in the specified destination as below.

[image: Final output]

Comment: Thank you! i really appreciate the step-by-step instructions.